# Stream data from azure python functions to client

Tags: python, download, azure-functions

I have a python program that generates data, it may rely on webservices to work which slows down the process.

I would like to expose this program as a web service that returns a file to download (content-disposition attachment)

I thought the easiest and cheapest option would be to go serverless.
I have quota on Azure so I want to try with Azure functions.

Azure http python functions must return a object `func.HttpResponse()` that takes the response body as parameter.

However, I would like not to generate the whole file in memory or in a temporary file before returning the response.
It could be big files and also file creation can be slow.

The file can totally be transferred back to the user as it is constructed. (return a httpresponse with chunk encoding)

It would make less wait for people calling the service and I believe reduce costs on the function (less memory used during concurrent calls)

Is it possible with Azure HTTP triggered function? If not with Azure, is it on GCP or AWS functions?

Comment: From this issue it seems to be possible with csharp only. https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1361

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [MiniScalope](https://stackoverflow.com/users/99276/miniscalope). Posting your comment as an answer to help other community members.

> As per the comment, you have found that it's only possible with C# as of now.

You can refer to [Out of proc languages stream support](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1361#issuecomment-779469223)